# iPhone: No events after rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation

for rotation of my app I use the same view and just rearrange some controls resp. define the appropriate autosize attributes. So, for example, I have a segmented control which goes from the left to the right over the complete screen. When rotating it resizes correct, but I get no events from the segments on the right side (I guess, segements which are located right of the original portrait width).

Does anyone know, why this happens? Thanks for your help.

Regards
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer by myself, even though I do not really understand it. Problem was, that I used for the view these "Simulated User Interface Elements". When using those the resize was not done properly. Without them it works perfect.